# Position multiple UIViews on a visual timeline with NSLayoutConstraint in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, timeline

I need to figure out how to position 3 - 5 UIViews (basically a circular drawn colored dot) on a horizontal line which reach from side to side on the screen with constraints. Or is it better to go without constraints?

The line should be based on a day (24 hours)

E.g - If I have 3 NSDates which represents three times (7:00, 12:00, and 22:00) I want them to be positioned correctly on the timeline:

|------7----12--------22-|

EDIT.
With a little more thinking I now see that I will not able to achieve this. The thing is that each dot on the timeline is, say a "todo"-time for a specific task. But there could be several tasks. And each task is a table cell. So there will be multiple timelines:

|------7----12--------22-|
|----5------12------20---|
|--------10-12-------21--|
|------7----12-----18----|

And because each dot has a label above it I will not be able to position the dots according to time. Because in vertical orientation theres not room for 24 positions. And therefor dots with the same time (in two different timelines) will not be align correctly.

How I solved it for now is by splitting each tasks times into two arrays, one with all times before 12.00 and another one with all times after 12.00.

I then take the first array starting with the earliest time from the left (constraint leading to superview) and the rest right to the view before and so on.

I then take the second array and starts from the end (latest time) and adding them to the right (constraint trailing to superview) and the rest left to the view before and so on.

This is the result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui6rS.png)

Comment: How about taking 24 equal sized UIView Horizontally?

Comment: I edited my question with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar. I return a UIImage for each tableview cell view with numbers laid out horizontally according to an NSDate. You'll just have to turn the NSDate into a CGFloat value. This extension gives me a decimal value representing hour and minute from an NSDate.

```
extension NSDate {
    var hourInDecimal: CGFloat {
        get {
            let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

            let timeNowInDecimal = CGFloat(userCalendar.component(.Hour, fromDate: self)) + CGFloat(userCalendar.component(.Minute, fromDate: self))/60
            return timeNowInDecimal
        }
    }
}
```

Fitting them horizontally was tough if it was 24 hours so I only go from the first hour to the latest hour with data. 7am -> 10pm did fit.

Then to get the distance from the left edge (for a constraint)...

```
let oneHourWidth = containerView.width/(lateHour - earlyHour)
let distanceToLeftEdge = oneHourWidth * (eventTime.hourInDecimal - earlyHour)
```

Note that some of the above changes for Swift 3.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I understand what you mean. 
But if all views have the from left edge constraint will they then not overlap each other, if the hour gap is only lets say 1 or 2 hour?
E.g three UIViews with the hour 07.00, 08.00 and 09.00.
Because my dot-views takes up a constant value of 25-30 in width.

Comment: I've tried your solution now without success.
I managed to get each successor view to position to the right of its predecessor by calculating the distance between the new and previous view. 
Calculation: (distanceToLeft_newView - distanceToLeft_predecessorView). But if there was a great amount of hours between two times (e.g 08.00 and 16.00) the third time was positioned way out of screen.
I think i'm stucked here...

Comment: If you're running into overlap, you might have to rethink your layout for this. Maybe alternate the hour labels, one above then one below then above... etc. Also.. if all the labels are specific to an hour on the dot, why bother with the extra zeroes for the minutes?

Comment: Yeah, I'm on a solution with just those ideas right now. However your example helped me a lot. It just need some more tweaking on how to organize the labels and some other stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Im not able to solve it that way either. The thing is that I also need the dot of the time closes to the current time to be 3 times larger than the rest of the dots. And without any constraint between each view I don't really have any options to solve it.
I'm thinking of changing the layout so that if the dots on the timeline reaches longer than the width of the screen the user needs to scroll horizontal to see the rest of the later times.
Meaning something like only a third of the timeline will be shown on the screen. To see the rest the user need to scroll horizontal to se the rest of it.

Comment: Yeah you could do that with a scrollview and pinch to zoom in each cell. What about making the top cell larger, showing the full day in a two or three   rows that are spaced nicely, and having the others shrunk so you can see the full day so when the user brings that day to the top of the tableView, the cell expands like this tutorial's collection view https://www.raywenderlich.com/99087/swift-expanding-cells-ios-collection-views.

Comment: I have each tableview inside a PageViewController, so if i swipe left or right the next or previously day is displayed instead. This makes the timeline just go on and on, if I cut it into three the "illusion" breaks. :P
But I will have a look at putting a CollectionView in each cell instead and just horizontally add 24 UIViews to it. And then set so the screen width just displays 6 of those views but with horizontal scroll enable to see the ones before and after.
The problem here will be how to know when I reach the end of the CollectionView and paging will be done (showing the next day).

Comment: Or by the way, I maybe can just use a CollectionView instead of the TableView.